# Why moodle block is not showing?

Tags: php, layout, block, moodle

I have fallowing `Moodle` [document](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks#Ready.2C_Set.2C_Go.21) for creating a new block, called "simplehtml" liked document, I can install this block, but why when I put this fallowing code in layout, it is not returning anything for rend?

Code in layout for call my block:

```
<?php echo $OUTPUT->blocks('simplehtml', 'span4 desktop-first-column'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how blocks work. Block is like a widget. Add it to the page using the interface:

https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Block_settings#Adding_a_block_to_a_page